# React-Router and iFrames

Tags: reactjs, react-router-v4

Is it possible to do some rules in React-Router to display only certain routes when a ReactJS app is being called from an iFrame?

I have the following routes, which as you can observe, will always display the `<Header />` and the `<Footer />` components:

```
...
<Route component={Header} />
<Route exact path="/" component={Landing} />
<Route path="/about" component={About} />
<Route path="/contact" component={Contact} />
<Route component={Footer} />
...
```

However when someone embeds my app in his website (like a widget) from an iFrame, I do not want to display the `<Header />` and the `<Footer />` components, so it will behave something like this:

```
...
<Route exact path="/" component={Landing} />
<Route path="/about" component={About} />
<Route path="/contact" component={Contact} />
...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maintain state or props for whether it is embeded in iframe or not. I used props in the below sample:

```
render() {
        return (
            <div>
                {this.props.inIframe !== null && this.props.inInframe !== true ? <Header /> : null}
                <Switch>
                    <Route exact path="/" component={Dashboard}/>
                    <Route path="/about" component={WebsiteEditor}/>
                    <Route path="/contact" component={WebsiteViewer} />
                </Switch>
                {this.props.inIframe !== null && this.props.inInframe !== true ? <Footer /> : null}
            </div>
        );
    }
```